# Any example of integration of Qt in some ROS package?

Tags: qt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

I would like to use an QT as an user interface for my mobile platform. I have a sensor package consist of IMU , Laser, Kinect and wheel encoders. Would like to have an input button that run a rose node than do something with the data and gives an output results. Any help or advice, or code suggestion regarding this?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/105516/any-example-of-integration-of-qt-in-some-ros-package?/) by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on ROS Answers with karma: 330 on 2013-11-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hamid Didari](https://answers.ros.org/users/6486/hamid-didari/) on 2013-11-27**:
you can add QT library in your pkg and use it like qt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In principle just use as any other library or as using Qt in any other cmake project.

This might help simplify the process: http://wiki.ros.org/qt_ros

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-11-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-11-27**:\

- Depending on what you want to do, check out rqt.

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2013-11-27**:
I have Fuerte version of ROS. Is qt_create works with Fuerte? Is there in general problems Using Qt in Fuerte version of ROS or do I need Electric one?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-11-27**:
I don't know if this works on fuerte, but Qt definitely works with problems. You'd just set that up like any other Qt + CMake project. ROS doesn't care about that.  The only thing I usually add is: ADD_DEFINITIONS(-DQT_NO_KEYWORDS) as I had some conflicts with signals/slots.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-11-27**:
Example: http://alufr-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/branches/freiburg_tools-groovy/rxparamedit/

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2013-11-28**:
You mean Qt definitely works without problems or??

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-11-28**:
Qt definitely works!

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2013-12-01**:
Ok. Thanks. So how you run it???

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2013-12-03**:
Hi dornhere. What is the difference between qt_ros and rqt? I could compile and run the deme from qt_ros. But I dont know which way to go? Using 1t_ros or rqt. What do you suggest?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-12-04**:
qt_ros AFAIK are just some tools the make creating a ROS package with Qt code easier. rqt is ROS' gui framework, where you can easily write plugins usually for visualization or simple commands (i.e. not processing).

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2013-12-04**:
I could not make working qt on ROS Fuerte. All my ROS code is on Fuerte and I dont wonna migrate to other ROS version.

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2013-12-04**:
In my job I have experience in making GUI both in qt_ros and rqt. I initially started from qt_ros, which worked great for me on `fuerte`. But if your Qt work is specific to GUI development, I recommend rqt, which has limited functionality in F-turtle but still works nice.

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2013-12-04**:
what do you mean F-turtle IsaacSaito ? Furte turtle? I would like to develop GUI. But if rqt has limited functionality in Furte than make no sens to develop GUI with rqt. Im bit confuse

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-12-05**:
f-turtle is fuerte. The basic decision is: Use rqt and build something for that vs. using a custom Qt built GUI in your program. That depends on what you need. If you just need a couple of buttons to trigger ROS calls or something like that rqt might be easier.

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2013-12-08**:
I dont think i need something simple. I need GUI that can start a launch file, run hactor mapping, run certain node ( i have 7 nodes, and need to choose with a button which node to be run), than have some output based on some extracted parameters from that node. So its not a simple one.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-12-09**:
This still sounds like it might be doable with rqt. There might even be some plugins that can run launch files. You might want to check that out.

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2013-12-09**:
so whats the advantage doing with rqt than with qt_ros?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-12-09**:
It's just different. Check out the rqt docs, examples, etc. especially with regard to what you get in fuerte. When you have seen what rqt does, you can decide for yourself.

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2013-12-09**:
ok..I check and seams there are many functions that are not available in Fuerte. For example running launch file no option on rqt  Fuerte.. I think will start with qt_ros.